# How to stop Eclipse IDE from trying to download DTDs for validation?

Tags: eclipse, validation, xhtml, w3c, dtd

I have a XHTML-file using the following doctype-definition:

```
`<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">`
```

Eclipse is trying to validate the file by using the referenced dtd file, which results in this error:

```
ParseException: Error validating the model: Server returned HTTP response code: 503 for URL: http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd
```

The reason is an intended error response, like described here:

[W3C's Excessive DTD Traffic](http://www.w3.org/2005/06/blog/systeam/2008/02/08/w3c_s_excessive_dtd_traffic)

So I tried to stop Eclipse from trying to download the file by disabling HTML validation, but this didn't help.

How can I get rid of the error message and stop Eclipse from trying to download the DTD-file?

edit: Eclipse-version is Galileo 3.5

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Which Eclipse version do you use? In 3.5 (Galileo), as default, the DTD for HTML/XHTML will be stored as local file and you won't get such problem.

You can also deactivate the XML validation, but not only the DTD check will be deactivated, but all XML validation.

EDIT: check the **Preferences -> XML -> XML Catalog** and check if the file has already referenced to local file. If not, you can add it yourself

Comment: how to deactivate xml validation?  That sounds like what the OP is asking